# Is getLastLocation of android locationManager using GnssAntennaInfo?

Tags: android-gps, android-gnss

I'm an Android developer.
From Android 11, the GnssAntennaInfo class that can utilize dual-frequency GNSS has been added, and it has been confirmed that developers can use it.
If so, is GnssAntennaInfo already used in getLastLocation method of locationManager provided by google location api??
Or is it still necessary for developers to utilize GnssAntennaInfo provided to improve location accuracy??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't give a definitive answer but, since there hasn't been any other response yet I'll answer what I'm pretty sure is the correct answer.

No.

From: https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/03/19/pixel-4-dual-band-gps/

> In the sheer infinite expanse of the Android 11 developer documentation, an entry for GNSS or dual-band GPS support has surfaced. While the Pixel 4 isn't explicitly mentioned, it's plausible that owners will be able to use the hardware once developers add support for the new GnssAntennaInfo class to their apps. Hopefully, Google Maps will be among the first to utilize it — even if the difference isn't too meaningful, it might make GPS more reliable.

This matches my own experience. I recently purchased an S20 hoping for this exact feature (~ 1 yard accuracy), currently I'm seeing ~ 4 yrds. I've confirmed I see L5 satellites and my phone just got the Android 11 update tonight. All of my GPS apps show **NO** improvement in accuracy. I'm unsure of Google Maps, don't really know how to tell with it. However, if some "provided" function like getLastLocation were benefitting from high accuracy I think I'd see it in my GPS apps.

Hence, if I can figure out exactly how L5 can improve accuracy, I' going to attempt to write this myself. I'm having a hard time tracking that info down though...